# Accessing processed values from FFT

Tags: c#, audio, fft, spectral-density

I am attempting to use [Lomont FFT](http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/LomontFFT.html) in order to return complex numbers to build a spectrogram / spectral density chart using c#.

I am having trouble understanding how to return values from the class.
Here is the code I have put together thus far which *appears* to be working.

```
    int read = 0;
    Double[] data;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    FileStream wave = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
    read = wave.Read(buffer, 0, 44);                                            
    read = wave.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);                                          
    data = new Double[read];                                                    


    for (int i = 0; i < read; i+=2)
    {
        data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i) / 32768.0;
        Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
    }
    LomontFFT LFFT = new LomontFFT();
    LFFT.FFT(data, true);
```

What I am not clear on is, how to return/access the values from Lomont FFT implementation back into my application (console)?

Being pretty new to c# development, I'm thinking I am perhaps missing a fundamental aspect of understanding regarding how to retrieve processed values from the instance of the Lomont Class, or perhaps even calling it incorrectly.

```
Console.WriteLine(LFFT.A); // Returns 0
Console.WriteLine(LFFT.B); // Returns 1
```

I have been searching for a code snippet or explanation of how to do this, but so far have come up with nothing that I understand or explains this particular aspect of the issue I am facing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

A subset of the results held in `data` array noted in the code above can be found below and based on my current understanding, appear to be valid:

```
0.00531005859375
0.0238037109375
0.041473388671875
0.0576171875
0.07183837890625
0.083465576171875
0.092193603515625
0.097625732421875
0.099639892578125
0.098114013671875
0.0931396484375
0.0848388671875
0.07354736328125
0.05963134765625
0.043609619140625
0.026031494140625
0.007476806640625
-0.011260986328125
-0.0296630859375
-0.047027587890625
-0.062713623046875
-0.076141357421875
-0.086883544921875
-0.09454345703125
-0.098785400390625
-0.0994873046875
-0.0966796875
-0.090362548828125
-0.080810546875
-0.06842041015625
-0.05352783203125
-0.036712646484375
-0.0185546875
```

**What am I actually attempting to do?** (perspective)

I am looking to load a wave file into a console application and return a spectrogram/spectral density chart/image as a jpg/png for further processing.

The wave files I am reading are mono in format

---

**UPDATE 1**

I Receive slightly different results depending on which FFT is used.

Using RealFFT

```
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i+=2)
    {
        data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i) / 32768.0;
        //Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
    }

    LomontFFT LFFT = new LomontFFT();
    LFFT.RealFFT(data, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}",
          Math.Sqrt(data[2 * i] * data[2 * i] + data[2 * i + 1] * data[2 * i + 1]));
    }
```

Partial Result of RealFFT

```
0.314566983321381
0.625242818210924
0.30314888696868
0.118468857708093
0.0587697011760449
0.0369034115568654
0.0265842582236275
0.0207195964060356
0.0169601273233317
0.0143745438577886
0.012528799609089
0.0111831275153128
0.0102313284519146
0.00960198279358434
0.00920236001619566
```

Using FFT

```
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i+=2)
    {
        data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, i) / 32768.0;
        //Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
    }

    double[] bufferB = new double[2 * data.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        bufferB[2 * i] = data[i];
        bufferB[2 * i + 1] = 0;
    }

    LomontFFT LFFT = new LomontFFT();
    LFFT.FFT(bufferB, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferB.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}",
          Math.Sqrt(bufferB[2 * i] * bufferB[2 * i] + bufferB[2 * i + 1] * bufferB[2 * i + 1]));
    }
```

Partial Result of FFT:

```
0.31456698332138
0.625242818210923
0.303148886968679
0.118468857708092
0.0587697011760447
0.0369034115568653
0.0265842582236274
0.0207195964060355
0.0169601273233317
0.0143745438577886
0.012528799609089
0.0111831275153127
0.0102313284519146
0.00960198279358439
0.00920236001619564
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `LomontFFT.FFT` documentation:

> Compute the forward or inverse Fourier Transform of data, with 
>     data containing complex valued data as alternating real and
>     imaginary parts. The length must be a power of 2. The data is 
>     modified in place.

This tells us a few things. First the function is expecting complex-valued data whereas your data is real. A quick fix for this is to create another buffer of twice the size and setting all the imaginary parts to 0:

```
double[] buffer = new double[2*data.Length];
for (int i=0; i<data.Length; i++)
{
  buffer[2*i] = data[i];
  buffer[2*i+1] = 0;
}
```

The documentation also tells us that the computation is done in place. That means that after the call to `FFT` returns, the input array is replaced with the computed result. You could thus print the spectrum with:

```
LomontFFT LFFT = new LomontFFT();
LFFT.FFT(buffer, true);

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length/2; i++)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine("{0}",
    Math.Sqrt(buffer[2*i]*buffer[2*i]+buffer[2*i+1]*buffer[2*i+1]));
}
```

Note since your input `data` is real valued you could also use `LomontFFT.RealFFT`. In that case, given a slightly different packing rule, you would obtain the FFT results using:

```
LomontFFT LFFT = new LomontFFT();
LFFT.RealFFT(data, true);

System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", Math.Abs(data[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < data.Length/2; i++)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine("{0}",
    Math.Sqrt(data[2*i]*data[2*i]+data[2*i+1]*data[2*i+1]));
}
System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", Math.Abs(data[1]);
```

This would give you the non-redundant lower half of the spectrum (Unlike `LomontFFT.FFT` which provides the entire spectrum). Also, numerical differences on the order of `double` precision (around `1e-16` times the spectrum peak value) with respect to `LomontFFT.FFT` can be expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what you have pointed out makes good sense to me. I appear to be receiving slightly different results depending on which FFT algorithm I use, RealFFT or FFT. I am not sure how significant this actually is though? Updated 1 in the OP describes this. @SleuthEye

Comment: @SleutheEye, so to clarify here, if I can only expect nyquist and below results from RealFFT, why is it we are dividing the `data.Length` by 2 `data.Length/2` in the for loop? Is this due to imaginary numbers being returned from RealFFT and the halving of `data.Length` used as a means to filter all items above the nyquist?

Comment: `data.Length/2` for the loop is due to complex numbers being made of an imaginary and real parts (ie. 2 `double` values per complex number). The fact that `RealFFT` only return the lower half of the spectrum implies that `data.Length == buffer.Length/2` (for a corresponding equivalent `buffer` used with `FFT` call). So, if you have 1024 real values, you'd have `data.Length==1024`, `buffer.Length==2048` and you'd execute the `RealFFT` snippet's loop body 511 times (we skip index 0, which contains 2 purely real component at 0Hz and Nyquist frequencies respectively).